# Entity Framework Many to Many with multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working with three tables: Models, Codes, and Projects, all linked through many-to-many relationships. A model can have many projects that introduce many codes. A project can include many models and many codes, and a code can have many models introduced by many projects.

I can and have gotten a basic many-to-many relationship done up in Code-First Migrations.  My question now is if there's any way to extend the relationship table to include a 3rd table? I think based off the documentation, I'd have tables for ModelCodes, ModelProjects, CodeProjects, etc... It seems disconnected and tedious.

Is EF designed to have a table ModelCodeProjects, i.e. similar to the model below:

```
 public class ModelCodeProject()
{
    public int ModelId {get; set;}
    public int CodeId {get; set;}
    public int ProjectId {get; set;}
}
```

If so, how would I possibly go about setting this up through migration code-first? Or am I just better off creating multiple Many-to-Many relationships?

Comment: What have you tried and what happened that makes you think it shouldn't work? And if you describe the tables correctly that a Model is linked to a Project then you don't really need the Project in your relation.

Comment: well i'm currently just trying to figure out how to. I have a ModelProjects table in my database, and it doesn't exist in my code first. So I'm having difficulty understanding how I can update that ModelProjects correctly and not upset how the code-first uses the table. I was going to try just manually adding the additional column, and basically have a 3-column look-up table.  It's really the implementation that I'm lost about.  And why would I not need the project in my relation?  Since it's a many-to-many, wouldn't I still need it?

Comment: If a project has a relation to a model and a model has multiple codes the relations shouldnt be in one three-way relation i would say

Comment: There is an answer below which isn't even related to the question. Have you ever able to get what you looked for? I am in your shoes right now and could use some help here...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just create multiple many-to-many relationships.

To delete a project with id# 5 that belongs to a model with id#3, you can do this:

```
 var projects = db.Model.Single(m => m.ModelId ==5).Projects;
 var projectToDelete = projects.Single(p => p.ProjectId ==3);
 projects.Delete(projectToDelete);
 dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

To update a project or model or code, you can just retrieve that instance from the database.

```
 var code = db.Codes.Single(c => c.codeId == 5);
 code.Text = "new code";
 dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```